# Jquery datatable sdom how to define id and class both

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to add one extra sdom in the JQuery datatable. So I have added the below shown structure as part of my total sdom. This is creating a div but the class is not coming.

Any idea what I may be missing. Let me know if you need any more info

```
<"#id"'class'>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, post some code.

Comment: Do you mean: https://datatables.net/ and https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it with a workaround:

```
sDom: '<"your-id-here">',
fnInitComplete: function() {
    $('#your-id-here').addClass('add your classes here');
}
```

Hope this helps.