# How to add an "id" and "class" in sDom using datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatables and im trying to add an "id" to a  that already has a "class" selector.

```
 "sDom": '<"account-list-header" Cf>tip'
```

Above code has a `class="account-list-header"`

I tried doing this:`"sDom": '<"account-list-header" Cf><"#top">tip',`, but it creates a sepearte div and does not attach the "id" to the same dis as of `account-list-header`.
How can i achieve this using the sDom? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it with a workaround:

```
sDom: '<"account-list-header">',
fnInitComplete: function() {
    $('#account-list-header').addClass('add your classes here');
}
```

Hope this helps.

BTW, your question is a duplicate of this:
[Jquery datatable sdom how to define id and class both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543449/jquery-datatable-sdom-how-to-define-id-and-class-both)

Answer (score 0):

*Try the following:* 
`"sDom": '<"#myId.myClass" Cf>tip'`

*...or in your case:* 
`"sDom": '<"#top.account-list-header" Cf>tip'`

The solution <s>is discribed [on the official homepage](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options), however it</s> is quite confusing without an example

Comment: Where is it described exactly? I only see two separate cases there: 1) '<"class" and '>' - div with a class OR 2) '<"#id" and '>' - div with an ID, however they never say that you can use BOTH at the same time! I think that I have tried last year what you are suggesting here and it did not work for me back then. Maybe it works now with a newer version of Datatables, but I really doubt it. Did you in fact test the solution you suggested? Did it really work for you? Please let me know because I am interested. Thanks!

Comment: It works for me on an old version of datatables (1.9 something). You are right though, that the link I gave did not say so. I really wonder, where I've found that solution, but I can tell you that it took some time to get it.